# Why .doc file takes more memory space than .txt file?

Tags: file, memory, text, doc

I have both .doc file and .txt file with only "1" as a content. But .doc file takes 10.9kb but .txt file only takes 1 byte.

Comment: Because they're different formats and store different things (eg, styles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A .txt file contains plain text characters of 1 byte, a .doc file includes all Word document metadata such as font style, size, page margins etc.

Answer (score 1):

Self exploration:

1. Save the document as a ".docx" file.
2. Rename `foo.docx` to `foo.docx.zip` (all Microsoft "X-document" files are zips).
3. Extract `foo.docx.zip`.

View the extracted XML files - most of the files related to additional [*metadata*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata) resources that are included in the saved Word Document.

A `.doc` file is essentially just an older binary version of a `.docx` file and contains similar metadata information. This can be viewed with a binary/hex editor.

(There are also structural differences when saving the content itself.)

The text file only contains the literal content - and nothing else - which is why it is the same size the content with a single byte encoding.